# Android закрытие приложения

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Как узнать когда приложение прекратило работу ? **( не метод onDestroy)**
А именно когда выгрузили из памяти
Например есть приложение при свайпе оно зарывается  , как в коде узнать , когда оно закроется?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Пробовал переопределить метод в сервисе onTaskRemoved() , только он работает не каждый раз не могу понять , как он работает

```
 override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    Log.e("onTaskRemoved", rootIntent.toString())

    stopSelf()
}
```

---

```
<service
        android:name=".supprot.MyServicesKillApp"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:stopWithTask="false"
        />
```

И что означает `android:stopWithTask="false"` не совсем понятно

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568315/how-to-handle-code-when-app-is-killed-by-swiping-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете создать сервис для такой задачи.

```
public class MyService extends Service {...}
```

Определите ваш сервис в AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".MyService" 
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" />
```

Когда внутри сервиса вызовется callback onDestroy() - вы поймете, что приложение умирает.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: called");
    // Ваш код

}
```

Comment: Так как он вызовется  , если сервис будет запущен ?